# How i can view pdf in browser in read only mode?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I use a jframe,embed to view pdf file.but there has a option to download But i need the pdf as read only mode..i.e User only can view the file,he can not download that file..I want to fix this problem.This is my code

```
<embed src="cover.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

[In the pdf view i want not to view this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCX0q.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PDF to ReadOnly in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078399/convert-pdf-to-readonly-in-browsers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing.  If you can view it, you can download it.

Furthermore, you have very little control over how PDFs display.  Sometimes they'll use Adobe Reader.  Sometimes the browser can generate a version of it on its own.

Comment: How can i generate the version,please

Comment: @AvijitBiswas What are you asking?

Comment: Sorry sir..That was a mistake

Answer (score -2):

Actually there is such thing. Look into PDF.js. I don't have time to explain much right now, but it's fully open source, made by Mozilla, and I've had a great experience using it.

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33700042)